# JQuery UI Icon Usage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have changed all elements that have a class of button into buttons of the UI type; I.e. `jQuery('.button').button()`
So any button regardless of its use I.e. save, cancel, edit has the same style. For some elements I want to add an additional class of 'ui-icon-pencil' or 'ui-icon-check' or 'ui-icon-closethick', can any one suggest a way of applying the associated framework icon to the button based on this additional class please?

Answer (score 0):

If the button is already initialized, you could change it's options like this:

```
$(".cancel").button("options", "icons", {
  secondary: "ui-icon-closethick"
  // or primary: "ui-icon-closethick" for icon before it
});
```